# Terraform module and square brackets syntax

Tags: terraform

I have the following module usage syntax, which I can not understand

```
module.cloudfront_function_route_host[0].cloudfront_function_arn
```

**Questions**:

- How comes, that the CloudFront function resource - is accessed via the square-bracket notation?
- Does the module return a list?
- Where in the module / terraform is this documented?

**Secondary question:**

- why in the module reference - underscores are used, but the module folder is called with dashes ("cloudfront-functions-route-host")

---

**Module definition in subfolder** `.\cloudfront-functions-route-host\`

> Observation: No "cloudfront_function_arn" property is exported, but
> still it is accessed via module

File **main.tf**

```
locals {
  bucket_name   = ...
  function_code = ...
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_function" "route_host" {
  name    = ...
  runtime = ...
  comment = ...
  publish = true
  code    = local.function_code
}
```

File **output.tf**

```
output "cloudfront_function_arn" {
  value = aws_cloudfront_function.route_host.arn
}

output "cloudfront_function_code" {
  value = local.function_code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How comes, that the CloudFront function resource - is accessed via the square-bracket notation?

The bracket notation is applied to the module itself. Probably you have the following module usage (or something similar) in your code somewhere:

```
module "cloudfront_function_route_host" {
  source = ".\cloudfront-functions-route-host"
  count = var.something ? 1 : 0 # probably you have some condition on which it is created or not
  ...
}
```

This snippet declares a *list of modules* (it has a `count` attribute), for which it makes sense to have the bracket notation. Otherwise, this code `module.cloudfront_function_route_host[0].cloudfront_function_arn` does not work.

> Does the module return a list?

No, it does not. As I said before, the bracket notation would apply to the module itself, not to the return.

> Where in the module / terraform is this documented?

This is not something we could answer based on your question.

> why in the module reference - underscores are used, but the module folder is called with dashes ("cloudfront-functions-route-host")

Returning to my previous snippet, note the folder (`source`) does not have to be the same as the module name.

> Observation: No "cloudfront_function_arn" property is exported, but still it is accessed via module

I don't really understand this statement.

```
output "cloudfront_function_arn" {
  value = aws_cloudfront_function.route_host.arn
}
```

This is what exports the property of `cloudfront_function_arn`. For more information you would want to check out Terraform [module outputs](https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs).

Comment: by "Where in the module / terraform is this documented?" I probably have meant the terraform-documentation about the ability to access the module itself with square brackets. Now, knowing about this possibility I found the documentation under https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count#referring-to-instances